# My cogs do not work discord.py/nextcord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, nextcord

My cogs do not work on nextcord.py

I have error like this:

```
help cannot be loaded. [Extension 'help' could not be loaded.]
Moderation cannot be loaded. [Extension 'Moderation' could not be loaded.]
other cannot be loaded. [Extension 'other' could not be loaded.]
cogs.help cannot be loaded. [Extension 'cogs.help' could not be loaded.]  
cogs.Moderation cannot be loaded. [Extension 'cogs.Moderation' could not be loaded.]
cogs.other cannot be loaded. [Extension 'cogs.other' could not be loaded.]
```

also, my code look like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extensions):
    if ctx.author.id == 606433100150472704:
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        await ctx.send("Cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не являетесь разработчиком...")


@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extensions):
    if ctx.author.id == 606433100150472704:
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        await ctx.send("Cogs is unloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не являетесь разработчиком...")

@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extensions):
    if ctx.author.id == 606433100150472704:
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        await ctx.send("Cogs is unloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не являетесь разработчиком...")

initial_extensions = [
    'help',
    'Moderation',
    'other'
]

for filename in os.listdir('./сogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}") #Загрузка всех когов

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as error:
            print('{} cannot be loaded. [{}]'.format(extension, error))
```

I think the problem is in the last lines of the code. When Im trying delete if **name** == '**main**' piece of code, bot starts to work but command do not work.

Comment: Remove following code `except Exception as error:
            print('{} cannot be loaded. [{}]'.format(extension, error))` and provide your errors.

Comment: ```
  File "c:\Users\Andriyko\Desktop\Ghost bot\ghost.py", line 55, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Users\Andriyko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 731, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name)
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'help' could not be loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the files for the cogs you should set them up using

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Cog(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
    print("Cog 'Cog' loaded")

def setup(bot):
  client.add_cog(Cog(bot))
```

In main.py, you should use

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix")

cogs = ["Cog", "moderation", "other", "etc"]
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  for cog in cogs:
    bot.load_extension(cog)
```

This way the bot should be able to load the extensions. You don't have to find the filenames using os

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be a better method:-

do this in `main.py`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='+', help_command=None, intents=discord.Intents().all())

        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                self.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

bot = Bot()

bot.run('token')
```

I hope this works! If it still doesn't work you may ask in nextcord's discord server or else create a new issue in the github page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any reputation to comment.

It would be best to remove the `except` statement so the full traceback can be seen.

```py
@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extensions):
    if ctx.author.id == 606433100150472704:
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        await ctx.send("Cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не являетесь разработчиком...")


@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extensions):
    if ctx.author.id == 606433100150472704:
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        await ctx.send("Cogs is unloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не являетесь разработчиком...")

@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extensions):
    if ctx.author.id == 606433100150472704:
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')
        await ctx.send("Cogs is unloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не являетесь разработчиком...")

initial_extensions = [
    'help',
    'Moderation',
    'other'
]

for filename in os.listdir('./сogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}") #Загрузка всех когов

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as error:
            print('{} cannot be loaded. [{}]'.format(extension, error))
```

If this error is still occuring, send your code and full traceback to the help channel in the [nextcord server](https://discord.gg/nextcord)